# How to prevent non-nullable types in Typescript including generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a situation very similar to this one: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22375.

The solution given there mostly works except for if I write a simple wrapper that just delegates to the existing implementation. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwIYDOAIsApisACYDyUAPACpygzAqUFwAUqlp5VZiFbtOTAPz4UATzgAuAFC9+FSgEoANHCIA+LgrhwAbngA2SYHLgMtfBHiSmYANTMWrRBWqtcmLNhxwymSqcJIURsBQ8tZqcAA+hkRwAN4GcFDAMEhQuCbmwHAAhAC8JUHsKoKS+RYxdg5OrgUA3AoAvgoKfGimeJnG-XAgVihIALYARlFtaDgE8CDJ5YQkIVS0XCBaAAxqLYYA9IfMUFDQCsdwAIJQAOYTbPAQCHAw0mCFY1NRcJicKAg8EIBEwdxQeEmpkKMAgcDA-Tw4yyvxebw+hQA5MEBJRMQA6Lo9PoDEzRaSjCbTKDxHGqWbzeDSZb4YhVGhQLjSXb7I4nCAAazw3LgzL+AKpUSJwF6-UKZLgAC8rAsoOQ7rTKutKAyUAslSzVuzNoqeQc4FdBcKtIrkv84Kr1Qk4Dsush0FgcA7MOMwNCAOpQPBgT70GzaPQwKwMTV2XG2DzeazxZJpQyZbK5VlrXGbGC2fYdBRAA)

I cannot figure out how to change the given solution to work with generic arguments. Is is known that I'm not supposed to be able to do this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please place all relevant information as text in the question itself, instead of only as external links, as mentioned in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler can't reason very well about whether a value is assignable to a type that depends on an unspecified generic type parameter, like the `T` and `D` inside the implementation of `simpleWrapper()`.  It *especially* cannot do it when the type is a [conditional type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) like `undefined extends T ? any : undefined`.  It mostly just gives up and says that any assignment you write is not valid.

There are several open GitHub issues that have to do with this limitation, but I don't know if any of them would address this particular code's issue if they were fixed.  One is [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085): the compiler cannot narrow union-typed generic type parameters based on control flow.  Another is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912): the compiler cannot tell if something is assignable to a generic conditional type, particularly when this is being returned from a function.

Most situations I've seen where this problem occurs can be addressed by the expedient and judicious use of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions); *you* know something is safe, but the compiler doesn't. So just tell it so:

```
function simpleWrapper<T, D>(t: T | undefined, d: D): T | D {
  return asDefinedOr(t as any, d);
}
```

Note that the compiler is not really trying to check the type safety for you anymore, so you have to be careful.

---

In this particular case it seems strange that you'd go through the trouble of coming up with a function that tries to complain if its first argument cannot possibly be `undefined` and then wrap it in something that explicitly does not care about this anymore, since `simpleWrapper(x, 0)` will not be an error.  In this case you might as well just go for the original implementation:

```
function simpleWrapper<T, D>(t: T | undefined, d: D): T | D {
  return t !== undefined ? t : d
}
```

Maybe I'm not understanding the use case, but I'd say to stay away from conditional type inference juggling unless you absolutely need it.

---

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwIYDOAIsApisACYDyUAPACpygzAqUFwAUqlp5VZiFbtOTAPz4UATzgAuAFBw4vfhUoBKADRwiAPi5LlcAG54ANkmBy4DHXwR4k5mADULVm0SMabXJixsHCrsaoKSFCbAUPK2GnAAPrpwAN5GUMAwSFC4ZpbAcACEALzFIQ4ClHCSeVaxDk4u7vkA3AoAvgoKfGjmeBmm-XAgNihIALYARtEtcApoOATwIERwZYQkZOq0XCA6AAwas3AA9CfMUFDQCmdwAIJQAOYTbPAQCHAw0mAFY1PRcEwnBQEHghAImEeKDwk3MBRgEDgYH6eHGmQB70+3wKAHJVFsqDiAHRdHp9AZmGLSUYTaYxJL4yptBYoJZwaSrdbEMI0KBcaQHI7KW4QADWeAF7NWQLgfzppOAvX6BUpcAAXjYllByI9EuUeczFvA1Zz8NyCbyuGrBccReLJSbAZwtTq9fsugpkOgsDg4BDxmA4QB1KB4MA-KAAJkYOn0XBgNiYDNCFvsXl8tj1qzSygyWRyZs2lR2YM4eBk9iOHQ9Xow2Fw-sDwBDYYjMd0BgTmeTFXUad0GaTyRzcDz2Vw8BKZUZ6mqn3q1YUjeDofD0V2NtO5zFEoUQA)